# Forgot password

Tags: bitcoin-core

I got myself a wallet back in 2015. I put bitcoins in there and forgot about them. Of course, because of the course, I remembered about this wallet, but I forgot the password. I have a wallet backup, but I can't do anything. Is it possible to remove the password from the wallet? please help me

Comment: Which wallet did you use? The answer will depend on that information.

Answer (score 1):

To recover your wallet you'll need to crack the password on it, since the password is used to encrypt the wallet file.

You can use a program like https://github.com/gurnec/btcrecover to attempt to crack it. If you have any idea of what the password might have been, you can supply them as hints to the program to have a better chance of cracking it. If the password was very long and you cannot provide a hint, you may be SOL until you remember it.