# bitcoin hash password

Tags: bitcoin-core

hope you doing well.
There is my question : after finding my old wallet.dat
it appear that I can't find any related project, others than hash cat
for finding my password.
So is there another way to find the password from the bitcoin hashes password?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Forgot password](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/102677/forgot-password)

Comment: nope sorry I alread tried btcrecover. I thought there is another way like a hash password to plain text for btc.

Comment: What do you mean by *"the bitcoin hashes password"*? - do you have a hash of the forgotten password? That would be a strange thing to have.